# Hacer programa consola C# menús y submenús

Tags: c#

Hice un ejemplo de hacer menús y submenús con una consola C# de 20x4. Solo se usan las flechas del teclado y Enter.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice un pedazo de código muy grande y repetitivo.

[Ver vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvT-dAeuNXg).

¿Pueden hacer un ejemplo?

Saludos.

PD: *Si me piden el código que hice, se los mando. Les advierto que es muy grande y repetitivo.*

Edito:
Código C#:

```
using System;
```

namespace Menu_consola_18_cs
{
class Program
{
// Variable general para guardar el > de la última opción que haz entrado
// en la hora de volver atrás. Por ejemplo:
private static int guardarOpcion = 0;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Console.Title = "Menú de opciones";

```
        // Tamaño ventana consola.
        // X anchura.
        Console.WindowWidth = 20;

        // Y altura.
        Console.WindowHeight = 5;

        // Ocultar cursor.
        Console.CursorVisible = false;

        // Fondo verde.
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        // Letras negras.
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

        MenuPrincipal();
    }

    #region Menú principal.
    public static void MenuPrincipal()
    {
        // Almacena la tecla pulsada en la variable.
        ConsoleKey teclaInicial;

        // Limpiar pantalla.
        Console.Clear();

        // Posición del cursor del título del MENÚ PRINCIPAL.
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);

        // Título.
        Console.Write("   MENÚ PRINCIPAL   ");

        // Pocisión de la hora.
        Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 2);

        // Formato numérico dd/MM/yyyy.
        Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd dd MMM"));

        // Almacena en la variable una tecla pulsada.
        teclaInicial = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        // ¿Haz pulsado la tecla Enter?
        if (teclaInicial == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            // Sí. Se ejecuta esta función.
            MenuOpciones();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Menú de opciones principales.
    public static void MenuOpciones()
    {
        // Contador de teclas y navegador.
        int opcion = 0;
        opcion = guardarOpcion;

        // Capturar tecla para luego validar.
        ConsoleKey tecla;

        while (true)
        {
            //******************************************************************
            // Dibujo el menú principal.

            // Limpiar pantalla.
            Console.Clear();

            switch (opcion)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.Write("> Opción A.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.Write("  Opción B.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.Write("  Opción C.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.Write("  Salir.            ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.Write("  Opción A.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.Write("> Opción B.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.Write("  Opción C.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.Write("  Salir.            ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.Write("  Opción A.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.Write("  Opción B.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.Write("> Opción C.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.Write("  Salir.            ");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.Write("  Opción A.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.Write("  Opción B.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.Write("  Opción C.         ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.Write("> Salir.            ");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.Write("Fuera de rango.     ");
                    break;
            }

            // Fin de pintar el menú principal.
            //******************************************************************

            // Leer tecla ingresada por el usuario.
            tecla = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            // Validar el tipo de tecla.
            if (tecla == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                switch (opcion)
                {
                    case 0:
                        OpcionA();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        OpcionB();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        OpcionC();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        guardarOpcion = 0;
                        MenuPrincipal();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Flecha abajo del teclado.
            if (tecla == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                opcion++;
            }

            // Flecha arriba del teclado.
            if (tecla == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                opcion--;
            }

            // Si está en la última opción del menú, salta a la primera.
            if (opcion > 3)
            {
                opcion = 0;
            }

            // Si está en la primera posición del menú, salta a la última.
            if (opcion < 0)
            {
                opcion = 3;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Opción A (0).
    public static void OpcionA()
    {
        ConsoleKey teclaOpcionA;
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción A.");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Pulse Enter para");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("Salir.");

            // Almacena el teclado pulsado en la variable teclaSubMenuA.
            teclaOpcionA = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        } while (teclaOpcionA != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Opción B (1).
    public static void OpcionB()
    {
        // Contador de teclas y navegador.
        int opcionB = 0;

        // Capturar tecla para luego validar.
        ConsoleKey teclaOpcionB;

        while (true)
        {
            switch (opcionB)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción B.  ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("> SubOpción B-1.    ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  SubOpción B-2     ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Salir.            ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción B.  ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("  SubOpción B-1.    ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("> SubOpción B-2     ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Salir.            ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción B.  ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("  SubOpción B-1.    ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  SubOpción B-2     ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("> Salir.            ");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.Write("Fuera de rango.     ");
                    break;
            }

            // Leer tecla ingresada por el usuario.
            teclaOpcionB = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            // Validar el tipo de tecla.
            if (teclaOpcionB == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                switch (opcionB)
                {
                    case 0:
                        OpcionB1();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        OpcionB2();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        guardarOpcion = 1;
                        MenuOpciones();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Write("Fuera de rango.     ");
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (teclaOpcionB == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                opcionB++;
            }

            if (teclaOpcionB == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                opcionB--;
            }

            // Si está en la última opción, salta a la primera.
            if (opcionB > 2)
            {
                opcionB = 0;
            }

            // Si está en la primera posición, salta a la última.
            if (opcionB < 0)
            {
                opcionB = 2;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Opcion B-1.
    public static void OpcionB1()
    {
        ConsoleKey teclaOpcionB1;
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción B-1.");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Pulse Enter para    ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("volver atrás.       ");

            // Almacena el teclado pulsado en la variable teclaSubMenuA.
            teclaOpcionB1 = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        } while (teclaOpcionB1 != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Opcion B-2.
    public static void OpcionB2()
    {
        ConsoleKey teclaOpcionB2;
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción B-2.");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Pulse Enter para    ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("volver atrás.       ");

            // Almacena el teclado pulsado en la variable teclaSubMenuA.
            teclaOpcionB2 = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        } while (teclaOpcionB2 != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Opción C (2).
    public static void OpcionC()
    {
        // Contador de teclas y navegador.
        int opcionC = 0;

        // Capturar tecla para luego validar.
        ConsoleKey teclaOpcionC;
        Console.Clear();
        
        while(true)
        {
            switch (opcionC)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción C.  ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("> Color 1.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 2.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Opción C-1.       ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción C.  ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 1.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("> Color 2.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Opción C-1.       ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción C.  ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 1.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 2.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("> Opción C-1.       ");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("> Color 3.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 4.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 5.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Salir.            ");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 3.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("> Color 4.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 5.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Salir.            ");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 3.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 4.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("> Color 5.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Salir.            ");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 3.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 4.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Color 5.          ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("> Salir.            ");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.Write("Fuera de rango.     ");
                    break;
            }

            // Leer tecla ingresada por el usuario.
            teclaOpcionC = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            // Validar el tipo de tecla.
            if (teclaOpcionC == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                switch (opcionC)
                {
                    case 0:
                        // Fondo azul.
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

                        // Letras blancas.
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // Fondo verde.
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

                        // Letras negras.
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        OpcionC1();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // Fondo negro.
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

                        // Letras rojo.
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        // Fondo negro.
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

                        // Letras rojo.
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        // Fondo negro.
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

                        // Letras rojo.
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        guardarOpcion = 2;
                        MenuOpciones();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Write("Fuera de rango.     ");
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (teclaOpcionC == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                opcionC++;
            }

            if (teclaOpcionC == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
            {
                opcionC--;
            }

            // Si está en la última opción, salta a la primera.
            if (opcionC > 6)
            {
                opcionC = 0;
            }

            // Si está en la primera posición, salta a la última.
            if (opcionC < 0)
            {
                opcionC = 6;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region OpcionC-1.
    public static void OpcionC1()
    {
        // Contador de teclas y navegador.
        int opcionC1 = 0;

        // Capturar tecla para luego validar.
        ConsoleKey teclaOpcionC1;
        Console.Clear();
        
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            switch (opcionC1)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción C-1.");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  SI");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(16, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("> NO");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción C-1.");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("> SI");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(16, 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("  NO");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.Write("Fuera de rango.     ");
                    break;
            }

            // Leer tecla ingresada por el usuario.
            teclaOpcionC1 = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            // Validar el tipo de tecla.
            if (teclaOpcionC1 == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                switch (opcionC1)
                {
                    case 0:
                        guardarOpcion = 2;
                        MenuPrincipal();
                        //Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        OpcionSI();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Write("Fuera de rango.     ");
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Flecha derecha.
            if (teclaOpcionC1 == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                opcionC1++;
            }

            // Flecha izquierda.
            if (teclaOpcionC1 == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                opcionC1--;
            }

            // Si está en la última opción, salta a la primera.
            if (opcionC1 > 1)
            {
                opcionC1 = 0;
            }

            // Si está en la primera posición, salta a la última.
            if (opcionC1 < 0)
            {
                opcionC1 = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region opcionSI del sub menú C-1.
    public static void OpcionSI()
    {
        ConsoleKey teclaOpcionB1;
        Console.Clear();
        do
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Estás en Opción SÍ.");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Pulse Enter para    ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("volver atrás.       ");

            // Almacena el teclado pulsado en la variable teclaOpciónB1.
            teclaOpcionB1 = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        } while (teclaOpcionB1 != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que tienes? ¿Podrías especificar?

Comment: Ví el vídeo, y creo que funciona perfectamente. Cuál error estás obteniendo, o que resultado esperabas? Saludos, por cierto mu buena música la del vídeo.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Les dejo el código, el problema que hice un código enorme, muy grande y repetitivo. Solo quiero simplificarlo. Se los dejo aquí el código, y si, funciona si, pero es muy grande para lo que es.
Ya puse el codigo arriba, en el hilo principal.

Comment: O sea.. tu pregunta es como podes hacer el codigo mas chiquito? que se puede reutilizar? te recomiendo buscas en tu codigo partes repetitivas y pasarlas a funciones...

Comment: Puedes hacer una función que evalúe todos los condicionales e invocarle cada vez que se ocupe, así te ahorras el trabajo de poner un condicional cuando se está en cada menú. Saludos

Comment: @fredyfx de acuerdo al 100%

Answer (score 1):

Lo que veo es que no haces un planteamiento práctico del problema para enfocar la solución. Creo que todo parte por crear un par de estructuras que nos simplificarán la vida:

```
struct MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(string p_Text, string p_Action)
    {
        Text = p_Text;
        Action = p_Action;
        linkMenu = new Menu();
    }
    public string Text;
    public string Action;
    public Menu linkMenu;           
}
```

Esta estructura será un elemento de menu que albergará información como el texto a mostrar, la acción que hace, y un enlace a un Menu si la opción requiere mostrar un submenú. El tipo Menu será de la siguiente forma:

```
struct Menu
{
    public Menu(string p_Title, MenuItem[] p_Items)
    {
        Title = p_Title;
        Items = p_Items;
    }
    public string Title;
    public MenuItem[] Items;
}
```

Con esto ya hemos hecho mucho, ahora ya podemos definir nuestros menus y para ello creamos una función:

```
// Alberga el menú principal de la aplicación.
static Menu MainMenu = new Menu();

private static void InitializeMenus()
{
    // Creamos los objetos
    Menu MenuSub1 = new Menu();
    Menu MenuSub2 = new Menu();

    // Conformamos la estructura de los distintos menus.

    // Crea MENU Principal
    MainMenu = new Menu("*  Principal  *", new MenuItem[]
                       {new MenuItem("0. Submenu UNO ", "MENU"),
                        new MenuItem("1. Submenu DOS ", "MENU"),
                        new MenuItem("2. SALIR       ", "TERMINAR") });
    // Crear SUB menu 1
    MenuSub1 = new Menu("* Submenu UNO *", new MenuItem[]
                       {new MenuItem("0. Opción A    ", "ACTION_A"),
                        new MenuItem("1. Opción B    ", "ACTION_B"),
                        new MenuItem("2. Regresar    ", "MENU")  });
    // Crear SUB menu 2
    MenuSub2 = new Menu("* Submenu DOS *", new MenuItem[]
                       {new MenuItem("0. Opción C    ", "ACTION_C"),
                        new MenuItem("1. Opción D    ", "ACTION_D"),
                        new MenuItem("2. Opción E    ", "ACTION_E"),
                        new MenuItem("3. Regresar    ", "MENU")  });
        
    // Una vez creados los distintos menus los enlazamos con las
    // opciones que albergan como acción la palabra 'MENU'
    MainMenu.Items[0].linkMenu = MenuSub1;
    MainMenu.Items[1].linkMenu = MenuSub2;

    MenuSub1.Items[2].linkMenu = MainMenu;
    MenuSub2.Items[3].linkMenu = MainMenu;
}
```

Vale, ahora vamos a crear otra función para dibujar un menu:

```
private static void DrawMenu(Menu p_Menu)
{
    // Primero el titulo del menu
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.Write(p_Menu.Title);

    // Las opciones del menu
    for (int i=0; i < p_Menu.Items.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i + 1);
        Console.Write(p_Menu.Items[i].Text);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

Esto nos simplifica mucho la vida ya que tenemos el mismo código para cualquier menu que queramos mostrar, basta con pasar el menú deseado como parámetro a la función.

Ahora toca crear una función que nos permita manejar la opción que elegimos cuando estamos en un menú. La siguiente función nos devuelve la opción de menú elegida relativa al menú pasado como parámetro:

```
private static MenuItem GetOption(Menu p_Menu)
{
    int curOption = 0;
    ConsoleKey getKey;
    // Dibujamos el menu actual.
    DrawMenu(p_Menu);
    // Esperamos una opción elegida por el usuario.
    do
    {
        // Resalta la opción actual 
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, curOption + 1);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Write(p_Menu.Items[curOption].Text);

        // Leer tecla ingresada por el usuario.
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, curOption + 1);
        getKey = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        // Quitamos el resalte
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, curOption + 1);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.Write(p_Menu.Items[curOption].Text);

        // Mueve la opción arriba/abajo según tecla pulsada
        if (getKey == ConsoleKey.DownArrow) curOption++;
        if (getKey == ConsoleKey.UpArrow) curOption--;
        if (curOption > p_Menu.Items.Length - 1) curOption = 0;
        if (curOption < 0) curOption = p_Menu.Items.Length - 1;

    } while (getKey != ConsoleKey.Enter);

    // Retornamos la opción de Menu seleccionada.
    return p_Menu.Items[curOption];
}
```

Bueno ya está casi todo hecho; vamos a ver como juntamos todo en el punto de entrada de la aplicación:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Inicializamos los menus de la aplicación
    InitializeMenus();

    // Título Aplicación.
    Console.Title = "GESTIONANDO MENUS EN CONSOLA";
    Menu currentMENU = MainMenu;  // Alberga el menú actual
    MenuItem currentMenuItem;     // Alberga la opción de menú elegida
    do
    {
        // Obtenemos una acción
        currentMenuItem = GetOption(currentMENU);
            
        if (currentMenuItem.Action == "MENU")
            currentMENU = currentMenuItem.linkMenu;
        else
            ProcessAction(currentMenuItem.Action);

    } while (currentMenuItem.Action != "TERMINAR");
}
```

Ya estamos apunto de terminar, como vemos primero obtenemos una opción de menú, y en base al elemento de menú seleccionado en su propiedad *Action* determinamos si se trata de un menú o si se trata de una acción a realizar. El el primer caso basta con actualizar el menú actual y en el segundo lo redirigimos a una función que procesa todas las acciones:

```
private static void ProcessAction(string p_Action)
{
    switch (p_Action)
    {
        case "ACTION_A":
            // Aquí código para la acción de menú elegida.
            break;
        case "ACTION_B":
            // Aquí código para la acción de menú elegida.
            break;
        case "ACTION_C":
            // Aquí código para la acción de menú elegida.
            break;
        .
        .
        . 
    }
}
```

Es todo, con esto basta que definas tus menus en *InitializeMenus()* y basta con que sitúes las acciones en esta última función. Cada acción de menú tendrá un texto único que la identifique. No importa la complejidad de los menús, el código es limpio y manejable. Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Excelente, solo hay que "pensar orientado a objeto" aunque se trate de un programa para la consola.!!!